# How to get WindowSize in GLFW for C++?

Tags: c++, glfw

I am developing an app using ImGui and GLFW, however I don't know how to get the Window size properly.

I do know that the `glfwGetWindowSize` does exist however I don't really understand how it works specifically the int and width params.

I have tried: initializing `int* w` and `int* h` and plugging those in the function. However that didn't work.

Comment: You might want to learn C++ before doing anything graphical. You’ll need a strong understanding of [pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) because they’re used everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using something like this:

```
int width, height;
glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
```

where window is your window instance. But if you are having problems with pointers then you should do as the comment suggested. However if you want to use pointers try this:

```
int* width = new int(0);
int* height = new int(0);
glfwGetWindowSize(window, width, height);
//do stuff with the values
delete width;
width = nullptr;
delete height;
height = nullptr;

//this will delete the value and delete the pointer
```

Comment: Don’t dynamically allocate an integer! What is this? Java?

Comment: I know it's just an example. Normally I would use the first solution as would most sane people